# Strange complex numbers equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having problems in understanding how to solve this complex equation:
$$z^2 + \bar{z} = i$$

I tried with $z = x + iy$ but in doing that I end up with

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 - y^2 + x = 0 \\
2ixy - iy = i
\end{cases}
$$

Which is not easy to solve.

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure about the equation? I ask this because the solutions are not nice, to say the least.

Comment: Multiply the first by $(2x-1)^2$, use the second to eliminate $y$ and you get a degree-four polynomial.  It's only when you try to solve the polynomial that it gets ugly.

Comment: @Empy2 Yes, that's the point... I am not able to solve that polynomial equation...

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, the equation is correct. The exercise asks me to tell where are placed the solutions in the Complex plane. I guess I can avoid to solve it, but how? For sure there are two complex solutions, but how can I figure where they are in the plane?

Comment: @Hans-André-Marie-Stamm Take the conjugate of the equation, then eliminate $\bar z$ between the two. You'll get a quartic in $z$ with $4$ complex solutions that add up to $0$. but the exact forms won't be pretty.